# Chrome loading inconsistently after Mojave upgrade

Tags: google-chrome, mojave

[image]After the Mojave upgrade my Google Chrome has consistently loaded slow and often will spin and not to connect to a website. The option is to switch to Safari (AS I Am doing now)

I have reset chrome, cleared all cache, uninstall and re-install.

When I force quit I do get a crash message that I share with google.

I have also tried both incognito as well as regular. See attached[image]

NOTE: I tried loading Chrome:extensions from chrome and it just spins without loading

See attached screen shot of what it does indefinitely

Comment: any Chrome extensions, plug ins add ons

Comment: what are your DNS servers settings ? try using google ones.

Comment: @Buscar웃 I will try removing all my Chrome extensions. For DNS, Safari is working great, Chrome is working inconsistently so I am not sure how DNS could matter

Comment: not all web browsers are made equal. Just try the 8.8.8.8 as DNS, it wont harm

Comment: Yes Thanks :) FYI: This is not working in Chrome -- chrome://extensions/ - Because this is not working I can't remove extensions.

Comment: what do you mean it is not working ?

Comment: By not working, I mean it just spins and eventually brings up a dialog box that says "untitled can not be loaded" 

The address in the address bar is "chrome://extensions"

Comment: When I type about:config into the address bar it redirects me to chrome://config and it spins

Comment: I added a screen shot of what my address bar looks like

Comment: I also have this problem with no solution. The only thing that works is if I disconnect from my wireless and reconnect. Somehow that works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I removed Google File Stream and now Chrome works!

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend you to remove all Google Chrome extensions via the command-line and then try again.

You might have one that is not working properly and causing it to crash. If you properly want to start fresh maybe following this might be an option:

https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/t_Q2_PZiXcA

Comment: I did this and it didn't help